# Image translation algorithm - Translate the Python algorithm to Julia language

Tags: python-3.x, julia

In python has the cv2 library and I have seen the following algorithm on this site:
https://medium.com/codezest/super-fast-color-transfer-algorithm-bd1a76bc7619

Ok. My goal is transform the same algorithm in julia language.

But I can´t do it. For example, I can´t I find a similar function to cv2.split and cv2.cvtColor for Julia language. Can anyone help me with this:?

Comment: Have you tried using [OpenCV.jl](https://juliaopencv.github.io/latest/)?

Comment: @JanWilamowski, thanks for your help. I did not try it. I didn't really know that. I was using https://juliaimages.org/stable/

Comment: I don't think this is a very good question for StackOverflow - consider posting on the JuliaLang Discourse instead where you can have more of a discussion. In general however it would be useful to break your problem down into workable chunks - "can anyone do this for me" is generally less well received than "the Python function `cv2.split` can do the following, is there a Julia package with similar functionality?"

Comment: @NilsGudat I only started in stackoverflow. I didn't know that about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analog of `cv2.cvtColor` is just `convert`:

```
julia> using Colors, FixedPointNumbers

julia> c = RGB{N0f8}(0.8, 0.1, 0.3)   # 24bit color
RGB{N0f8}(0.8,0.102,0.298)

julia> convert(Lab, c)
Lab{Float32}(44.379047f0,66.710754f0,19.784866f0)

julia> convert(RGB, ans)
RGB{Float32}(0.8f0,0.10196085f0,0.29803917f0)
```

And you can compute statistics very easily like this:

```
julia> using Colors, Statistics, StaticArrays

julia> a = rand(RGB{N0f8}, 5, 5)
5×5 Array{RGB{N0f8},2} with eltype RGB{N0f8}:
 RGB{N0f8}(0.58,0.494,0.353)   RGB{N0f8}(0.533,0.859,0.988)  RGB{N0f8}(0.604,0.078,0.459)  RGB{N0f8}(0.063,0.808,0.333)  RGB{N0f8}(0.529,0.859,0.114)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.141,0.455,0.82)   RGB{N0f8}(0.941,0.361,0.251)  RGB{N0f8}(0.773,0.086,0.392)  RGB{N0f8}(0.09,0.933,0.776)   RGB{N0f8}(0.039,0.063,0.784)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.259,0.29,0.255)   RGB{N0f8}(0.745,0.992,0.914)  RGB{N0f8}(0.902,0.973,0.949)  RGB{N0f8}(0.89,0.988,0.678)   RGB{N0f8}(0.051,0.29,0.016)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.267,0.349,0.129)  RGB{N0f8}(0.612,0.831,0.329)  RGB{N0f8}(0.278,0.196,1.0)    RGB{N0f8}(0.616,0.714,0.047)  RGB{N0f8}(0.298,0.922,0.486)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.0,0.706,0.243)    RGB{N0f8}(0.933,0.482,0.769)  RGB{N0f8}(0.016,0.196,0.196)  RGB{N0f8}(0.592,0.996,0.067)  RGB{N0f8}(0.271,0.071,0.02)

julia> mean(a) do c
           l = convert(Lab, c)
           SVector(l.l, l.a, l.b)
       end
3-element SVector{3, Float32} with indices SOneTo(3):
 59.578194
 -6.569998
 12.796135
```